# Prove that $S$ is compact.

Tags: complex-analysis, compactness

Prove that $$S:= \left \{f \in \mathcal H(\Bbb D)\ \bigg |\ f(z) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n,\ \text {with}\ |a_n| \leq n,\ \text {for all}\ n \in \Bbb N \right \}$$ is compact.

How do I proceed? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\mathcal H(\Bbb D)$ is holomorphic functions on the disc? With what metric/topology?

Comment: @Romain S it is not given. But I think the underlying metric is sup metric. Here $\mathcal H(\Bbb D)$ is the collection of all holomorphic functions defined on the unit disk.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: On the other hand, if the answers are not quite what you were hoping for, consider commenting to explain how you wish for them to be improved.

Answer (score 1):

Recall $\mathcal{H}(\mathbb{D})$ is a Fréchet space with the Heine-Borel property, as detailed in [this neat document](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/54f7/5352a18963ec11e294e562643bae9822ad88.pdf) (which contains way more detail about this proof, along with many other subjects). Now, all that remains to show is that $S$ is closed and bounded. Closeness is immediate, but boundedness is more delicate since $\mathcal{H}(\mathbb{D})$ is not normable. We instead look at all seminorms $\nu_{K_n}$, defined by
$$\nu_{K_n}(f)=\sup_{z\in K_n}|f(z)|$$
where $K_n=\{z\in \mathbb{D}\,|\,|z|\leq 1-1/n\}$. Showing all such seminorms are bounded on $S$ will allow us to conclude the result. Now, compute
$$|f(z)|\leq\left|\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n\right|\leq\sum_{n=0}^\infty n|z|^n=\frac{|z|}{(1-|z|)^2}.$$
It follows that $\nu_{K_n}(f)\leq n(n-1)$, from which we conclude that each seminorm is indeed bounded on $S$, and hence $S$ is compact.

Answer (score 1):

This is very likely to be a question about normal families.

Let $H=K$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb D$. Then there exist $r \in [0,1)$ such that $|z| \leq r$ for all $z \in K$. This gives $|f(z)| \leq \sum n r^{n}$ for all $z \in K$. Thus the given family is uniformly bounded on compact sets. The result now follows by Montel's Theorem.

Comment: What is Montel's theorem sir?

Comment: The question is clearly one about holomorphic functions so it is a question in Complex Analysis. Almost any book on Complex Analysis has Montel's Theorem which says that a family of analytic functions on a domain forms a relatively compact set  (w.r.t the topology of uniform convergence on compact sets ) iff the family is uniformly bounded on each compact subset. You can find this theorem on Wikipedia. @Phibetakappa

Comment: sir I am not acquainted with this theorem as the course in complex analysis which we had in first semester in our university doesn't include this theorem and now I'm in the final semester of my masters.

Comment: @Phibetakappa See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_family